# React Native: Array.map not rendering within Scrollview

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to render a list of items within a ScrollView Component from an array of data, but for some reason the items are not showing up, or perhaps rendering at all!? From the example below, only `<SomeOtherComponent />` shows up, when there should be three orange squares before it (assuming `this.state.test` is an array of, say, `[0, 1, 2]`). What am I doing wrong?

```js
<ScrollView
  style={{flex: 1}}
  contentContainerStyle={{width: '100%', alignItems: 'center'}}>
  
  {this.state.test.map((item, index) => {
    <View style={{height: 50, width: 50, backgroundColor: 'orange', marginBottom: 10}} />
  })}
  
  <SomeOtherComponent />
</ScrollView>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to return each mapping!

```
  {this.state.test.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <View style={{height: 50, width: 50, backgroundColor: 'orange', marginBottom: 10}} />
        )
  })}
```

Comment: After returning also the component is not rendering there are no errors in console even.

Answer (score 5):

You are not returning anything in your map function. `=> {}` suggests a function.

Use `=> {return <Component/>}`
or `=> <Component/>`

Comment: Or `=> (<Component/>)` if the multi-line JSX is preferred, just replace the `{ ... }` with `( ... )`

Answer (score 5):

You need to return the component inside `map` you can do as @wnaman says in the other answer or you can just remove the `{` `}` braces and it will return as expected.

```
  {this.state.test.map((item, index) => 
    <View style={{height: 50, width: 50, backgroundColor: 'orange', marginBottom: 10}} />
  )}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of curly brackets around the map function use parenthesis instead.

with parenthesis

```
{this.state.test.map((item, index) => (
<View style={{height: 50, width: 50, backgroundColor: 'orange', marginBottom: 10}} />
))}
```

---

with curly brackets - adding a return inside the map function

```
{this.state.test.map((item, index) => {
  return (
   <View style={{height: 50, width: 50, backgroundColor: 'orange', marginBottom: 10}} 
   />
  )
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have imported ScrollView from `react-native` **(not `react-native-web`)**.

Replace the following import statement,

```
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-web';
```

with

```
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
```